# my multiple alarms does not work | android

Tags: android

hi i have a problem with my code in the multiple alarm . i typed my code to be work on a multiple alarms every alarm take 10 seconds to be triggered REPEATEDLY. my problem that the alarm work with just one value but although i have put a  different requestCode, but it cannot bet work or i don't know how i call every one separately  .

the problem is i'v try to do this--->

alarm1 with a value and a request code 0 (for example) for 10 seconds

alarm2 with a different value and a request code 1 (for example) for 10 seconds

the code do this---->
desplay an just alarm2 that i selected lately

```
static int HELLO_ID = 1;
boolean flag = false;
int CountMultipleAlarm = 0;
EditText edt,edt2;
Button btn;
CountDownTimer timer;
//the strings of the notifications
String titlePills = "Time to take Panadol",DescriptionPills  = "Panadol";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
 R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
 btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 //hide the button and the edit text
 btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 edt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

> ```
> btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>               final String edittext= edt.getText().toString();  
>               Pattern pat= Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
>              // Pattern pat= Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
>               Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(edittext);  
>                 //*************Timer Start *************************8
>                 //11000 = 10 seconds(11000*6*60 == 1hour)
>                 int count = 11000;
>                 timer = new CountDownTimer(count, 1000) 
>                 {public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
>                      {
>                       long scnds=0;
>                          scnds=(millisUntilFinished/1000);
>                      }
>                      public void onFinish() 
>                      {//Alaram cooooode **********************************************************
>                           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       //for using this you need to import java.util.Calendar;
>
>                            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
>                            ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
>                             //the title and the description of the notification
>                            Intent alarmintent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Alarm_Receiver.class);
>                              alarmintent.putExtra("title",titlePills + "value");
>                              alarmintent.putExtra("note","value");
>                              //HELLO_ID is a static variable that must be initialized at the BEGINNING OF CLASS with 1;
>
>                              //example:protected static int HELLO_ID =1;
>                              PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(parent.getContext(), CountMultipleAlarm++,
>                              alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>                              //VERY IMPORTANT TO SET FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT... this will send correct extra's informations to 
>                              //AlarmReceiver Class
>                                   // Get the AlarmManager service
>
>                              am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
>
>                            //Alarm coooooode end **************************************
>                               intentArray.add(sender);
>
>                            timer.start();
>                      }
>               }.start();
>                 //*************Timer Ends *************************8
>       }
>   });
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
>
>
>   }import
> ```

and this is the alarm_Receiver class

```
    public class Alarm_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


String notification1 = "You Pills Time ";
private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)     
          context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,   notification1,
     System.currentTimeMillis());
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
    NOTIFICATION_ID, 
     new Intent(context, Alarm_Receiver.class), 0);
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
    String title=extras.getString("title");
               //here we get the title and description of our Notification
        //
    String note=extras.getString("note");
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
           //here we set the default sound for our 
            //notification

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);



}

        };
```

Comment: please, take care of the formatting, try to avoid horizontal scroll as possible.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what i do ,,,, (my english not perfect 100%)

Comment: your English is ok, :-) i just was complaining about the extra white spaces to the left, that genereta a big horizontal scroll, and difficult the reading. Thanks @keshav!

Comment: Remove `| Intent.FILL_IN_DATA` from the call to `getBroadcast()`. That doesn't belong there.

Comment: yes i got it than you i will edit the post ,,,, thank you again for the advice :)

Comment: @DavidWasser  that's just my problem ?

Comment: because i removed t but still have a problem overwrite the old one always

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the old one because the request code that you use in `getBroadcast()` is always zero.

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(parent.getContext(), i++, alarmintent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

The value of `i` is always zero, because you always set it to zero before calling `getBroadcast()`.

Comment: i change it but still have the problem ,,, i declared the i as a public variable on the top of the code ,,, but nothing changed :(

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What doesn't happen that is supposed to happen?

Comment: my problem is i tried to put a more than one alarm(lets say 2 alarms) for every alarm a different name i select it from the application ,,, but every time i select a different name ,,, it display a one alarm with just one name

Comment: How do you put in more than 1 alarm? what happens? How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: i put it in an array to to have multiple alarm ,,, it must be work

Comment: my problem is i tried to put a more than one alarm(lets say 2 alarms) for every alarm a different name i select it from the application ,,, but every time i select a different name ,,, it display a one alarm with just one name,,,

Comment: i select 2 different names but the code display one alarm with one name that i selected lastly

Comment: Well, you haven't posted any of that code so it is difficult to see the problem. You'll need to show more code.

Comment: i can show you all of my code but i don't wan't to distract anyone ,,,, but i will edit the code now with the full version and the alarm receiver class

Comment: Make sure that you remove any unnecessary white space. People don't like to scroll around to read your code.

Comment: sorry but i don't know how i do it this is the first time i use this website ,,, i am so sorry about these things i will try to do it very quickly ,, sorry again ,,,

Comment: I'm really sorry. I can't wade through all that code. You need to narrow down where your problem is first. Maybe write a small application to determine how the alarms, broadcast receivers, notifications and everything works. I can't tell from your question and comments if the problem is in the UI, in the alarm, in the notification, or what. You need to have a basic understanding of what you are doing and you need to be able to describe exactly what isn't working.

Comment: no don't worry thank you for helping me ,,, i will try to do a small one ,,,, thank you again :)